# How to make a copy of a project in RStudio Posit Cloud

Tags: r

I am working in a group for a final project in R and we used Posit Cloud so that it would be easy for us to contribute. However when I do my portion of the project, after I leave the website my code doesnt save. I dont have the option to make a permanent copy on the top right. Does anyone know how to contribute code and have it saved?? the auto save and manuak save (crtl + s) feature doesnt seem to work either

I did not want to export the file because I wanted to keep it in Posit so that my group memebers could collaborate easier. The other save options have not worked for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Who is listed as the owner of the project? There should be a name next to the project name. If it's not you, has that person added you to the project as a viewer, contributor, moderator, or admin?